# Create hotspot on boot (without login)

Tags: boot, networking, wireless, hot-spot, ap-hotspot

**Wish:** I want my Hotspot to be created during boot, so that I don't have to log in and manually start the Hotspot every time.

**System:** Ubuntu Mate 16.04

**WiFi card:** `# lsusb: Atheros Communications, Inc. AR9271 802.11n`

```
# lshw -class network
   description: Wireless interface
   physical id: 2
   bus info: usb@1:4
   logical name: ***
   serial: ***
   capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k_htc driverversion=4.4.0-75-generic firmware=1.4 ip=*.*.*.* link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

**Wish elaborated:**
The WiFi card is hotspot-able: I have it running as a hot spot right now.
I start the hotspot by clicking the network manager in the menu bar, then selecting "Create New WiFi Network...", and then, under "Connection", I select the WiFi-AP as I had already set it up some time ago.

Works like a charm.

But it requires me to log in to my user account, keep that account logged in (others use the computer as well, under their own accounts), and to manually start the Hotspot.

Now I would like to have the Hotspot created automatically (no user input) outside a user account (no log in).

Is this possible and how do I go about setting this up? I have searched the Internet and here, but didn't find anything that helped me on my way.